# phantomjs cookie "expires" vs "expiry"

Tags: cookies, properties, phantomjs

In phantom JS cookies have two properties.

http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/cookies.html

"expires" and "expiry"

I don't understand why it has two properties instead of one.

Can I just use the "expiry" timestamp and ignore the "expires"?

Answer (score 0):

According to the ['add-cookie' documentation](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/add-cookie.html) it's only documented to add `expires` as a numeric.

```
phantom.addCookie({
  'name'     : 'Valid-Cookie-Name',   /* required property */
  'value'    : 'Valid-Cookie-Value',  /* required property */
  'domain'   : 'localhost',
  'path'     : '/foo',                /* required property */
  'httponly' : true,
  'secure'   : false,
  'expires'  : (new Date()).getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60)   /* <-- expires in 1 hour */
});
```

It's not clear what is intended in the example in the [cookies documentation](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/cookies.html) however, as there are approximately two years between `expires: 'Sat Oct 11 2014 21:44:33 GMT+0200 (CEST)'` and `expiry: 1476128618` which is Monday 10th October 2016 07:43:38 PM.

Comment: I think it's just a slip in the docs, real examples show me that the two dates are equal